# r Shiny Using data frame column for choices

Tags: r, shiny

I'm really new to R, so this is probably an easy and obvious fix.

I'm trying to create a function that I can call to create selectInput boxes using the name of a column in a data frame with the choices being the

Dataset is the name of the data frame and characteristic is the name of a column within the frame.  I'm trying to use the characteristic name as the title of the input box, the values from within the column as the dropdown box options, and store the input in a variable called I(characteristic).

```
NewCharacterBox <- function(Characteristic, Dataset)
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           selectInput(paste("I", toString(Characteristic), sep = ""), h5(toString(Characteristic)),
                       choices = Dataset$Characteristic
```

Comment: so you want checkboxes with all the column names of the dataframe? Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you probably don't need a new user-defined function for that rather can simply use `names(dataset)`. Below is an example of that.

```
library(shiny)

data = iris

ui = fluidPage(

  selectInput("choice","List of Columns", 
              choices = names(data),
              selected = NULL),
  textOutput("selected"),
  tableOutput("result")
)


server = function(input, output) {

  output$selected <- renderText({
    paste("You have selected", input$choice)
  })

  output$result <- renderTable({
    data[,input$choice]
  })
}




shinyApp(ui,server)
```